# How can I get a `Makeheaders` binary for Windows?

Tags: c, windows, build

I'm tired of seperately having to generate a declaration in the header file for most of the functions I'm defining in my C file. Hence, I would like to automatize this.

I've found an ideal application for this: `Makeheaders`

Unfortunately only the sources seem to be available, no readymade binary.
Documentation: https://www.fossil-scm.org/xfer/doc/trunk/src/makeheaders.html
Code: https://code.launchpad.net/~lockal/makeheaders/head

Does someone know where to get a binary? Would it be hard to somehow build it myself?

Answer (score 2):

You can download the source code from [here](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/mkhdr/makeheaders.c). It is a single makeheaders.c file. 
then you just need to call `cl.exe makeheaders.c` it will generate a makeheaders.exe that you can use.